# Nano 2.0.6 - Saving a file in Mac Format

Tags: nano

Any ideas how to save a file edited with Nano, in "Mac format"? I keep getting DOS carriage returns in my newly-saved files on my Linux box. I provided a screen shot of the bottom menu when I go to "write out" file:

M-M Mac Format??? I see that there are save options when saving but cannot figure out how to execute them

[image]

M-M                     Toggle the use of Mac format

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The command "M-M" means "alt M". In fact, any command starting with "M" means the alt key. Some keyboards gobble up the alt key: in my case, on a Macbook Pro Retina, "esc" followed by "M" is what worked. More info [here](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nano.html).

However, since your screenshot is showing `[DOS Format]` as the current selection, the key combination you really want is "alt D" (or "esc" followed by "D"). That will toggle off `[DOS Format]` so that you'll be saving your file with the default line-ending character (ASCII 0xA). Turning on `[Mac Format]` will just give you a new set of problems.

Answer (score 5):

Normally you neither want to save as DOS format nor in Mac format. On Linux you should prefer the Unix format, therfore:

- enter a filename
- press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

and the file will be saved with the default Unix line-endings (which is what you want on Linux):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396551/gnu-nano-2-dos-format-or-mac-format-on-linux?noredirect=1#comment707780_396551

Comment: This one was what I just needed, as I'm newbie to Mac!

Answer (score -4):

There is no Mac format anymore. Mac OS X is UNIX.

Comment: I added a screen shot that shows the problem. Looks like the editor is defaulting to  DOS Format and I don't know how to execute the commands in the bottom menu: "M-M" ??